# Ajax php page and url change on load using load() function without refreshing

Tags: php, ajax, url, load, page-refresh

I am recently Creating a Blog site and it is based on php version 5.6.Now I am stuck over a week to achieve "ajax page load as well as url changing when click on navigation without refreshing the entire page". I have followed many suggestion from stakeoverflow and jQuery Forum.But own't make it properly. I have menu with `dropdown` and also have `dropdown-toggle` data attribute. Somtimes my code works fine but `dropdown` and `dropdown-toggle`won't work. Can anyone give me the way to achieve this.I am just a beginner of ajax. Here is my code.

**header.php**

```
        <?php
    require_once "../vendor/autoload.php";
     include "../lib/Database.php";
     include "../config/config.php";
     include "../helpers/Format.php";
    $fm= new Format();
    $db = new Database();
    $query ="SELECT * FROM `tbl_post` LIMIT 5";
    $post = $db->select($query);
    ?>
    <!doctype html>
    <html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/html">
    <head>
        <?php  include '../scripts/meta.php';?>
        <?php  include '../scripts/css.php';?>
    <?php include "../scripts/js.php";?>
    </head>
    <style>
        .row{
            margin:0;
        }
    </style>
    <body>
    <!-- header starts -->
    <header>
        <section id="smedia">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-8 navbar-left">
                        <p><a href="../Template/contact.php">PHONE: 01971982959</a> </p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-4">
                        <?php
                        $slgQuery = "SELECT * FROM `tbl_social` WHERE `id`= '1'";
                        $socialMedia = $db->select($slgQuery);
                        if($socialMedia )
                        {
                        while($socialResult = $socialMedia->fetch_assoc()) {
                        ?>
                        <a href="<?php echo $socialResult['fb']; ?>" target = "_blank"><i class="fa fa-facebook-official" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
                        <a href="<?php echo $socialResult['tw']; ?>" target = "_blank"><i class="fa fa-twitter" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
                        <a href="<?php echo $socialResult['pin']; ?>" target = "_blank"><i class="fa fa-pinterest-p" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
                        <a href="<?php echo $socialResult['gplus']; ?>" target = "_blank"> <i class="fa fa-google-plus" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
                        <a href="<?php echo $socialResult['ln']; ?>" target = "_blank"> <i class="fa fa-linkedin" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
                        <?php
                        }
                        }
                        ?>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </section>
        <!-- Navbar Starts -->
        <div class="row">
        <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
            <div class="container">
                <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
                <div class="navbar-header">
                    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
                        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    </button>
                    <a class="navbar-brand" href="../Template/index.php">
                    <?php
                    $slgQuery = "SELECT * FROM `title_slogan` WHERE `id`= '1'";
                    $getTitle = $db->select($slgQuery);
                    if($getTitle)
                    {
                        while($slgResult = $getTitle->fetch_assoc())
                        {
                    ?>
                  <img src="../Dashboard/admin/<?php echo $slgResult['logo'];?>" alt="logo" class="img-responsive">
                            <?php
                        }
                    }
                    ?>
                    </a>
                </div>
                <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                        <?php
                        $path = $_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME'];
                        $currentPage = basename($path,'.php');
                        ?>
                        <li <?php if($currentPage == 'index'){echo 'class ="active"';}?>><a  href="../Template/index.php">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>

                        <li <?php if($currentPage == 'Excellent'){echo 'class ="active"';}?>>

                            <a   href="#" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Post<span class="caret"></span></a>

                            <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dLabel">
                                <?php
                                if ($post){
                                while($result = $post->fetch_assoc())
                                {
                                ?>
                                <li><a href="../Template/Excellent.php?id=<?php echo $result['id'];?>"><p><?php echo $result['title'];?></p></a></li>
                                <?php }
                                }else{
                                    echo "data not Found!!";
                                }?>
                            </ul>

                        </li>
                          <?php
                         $aboutQuery = "select * from `tbl_page`";
                         $navigation = $db->select($aboutQuery);
                         if ($navigation)
                         {
                             while($aboutResult = $navigation->fetch_assoc())
                             {
                                 ?>

                        <li id="nav_link"
                            <?php if (isset($_GET['pageid'])&& $_GET['pageid']== $aboutResult['id'])
                            {
                                echo 'class ="active"';
                            }
                            ?>
                        > <a href="../Template/page.php?pageid=<?php  echo $aboutResult['id'];?>"><?php  echo $aboutResult['name'];?>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                                 <?php
                             }
                         }
                        ?>
                        <li <?php if($currentPage == 'contact'){echo 'class ="active"';}?> ><a href="../Template/contact.php">Contact</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
            </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
        </nav>
        </div>
        <!-- Navbar Ends -->
    </header>
    <!-- header ended -->
```

**js.php**

```
 $('#nav_link li a').click(function (e) {
     e.preventDefault();
     var navPage=$(this).attr('href');
     // alert(navPage);
     $(document.body).load(navPage).fadeIn('slow');
     $('.dropdown-toggle').dropdown();
     if(navPage!==location.href){
         window.history.pushState({path:navPage},'',navPage);
     }
     return false;
 });
```

Any help will be appriciate or please enlighten me.Thanks in advence

**Update**
HERE IS THE UPDATE

**header.php**

```
        <?php
   // require_once "../vendor/autoload.php";
     include "../lib/Database.php";
     include "../config/config.php";
     include "../helpers/Format.php";
    $fm= new Format();
    $db = new Database();
    $query ="SELECT * FROM `tbl_post` LIMIT 5";
    $post = $db->select($query);
    ?>
    <!doctype html>
    <html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/html">
    <head>
        <?php  include '../scripts/meta.php';?>
        <?php  include '../scripts/css.php';?>
    </head>
    <style>
        .row{
            margin:0;
        }
    </style>
    <body>
    <!-- header starts -->
    <header>
        <section id="smedia">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-8 navbar-left">
                        <p><a href="../Template/contact.php">PHONE: 01971982959</a> </p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-4">
                        <?php
                        $slgQuery = "SELECT * FROM `tbl_social` WHERE `id`= '1'";
                        $socialMedia = $db->select($slgQuery);
                        if($socialMedia )
                        {
                        while($socialResult = $socialMedia->fetch_assoc()) {
                        ?>
                        <a href="<?php echo $socialResult['fb']; ?>" target = "_blank"><i class="fa fa-facebook-official" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
                        <a href="<?php echo $socialResult['tw']; ?>" target = "_blank"><i class="fa fa-twitter" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
                        <a href="<?php echo $socialResult['pin']; ?>" target = "_blank"><i class="fa fa-pinterest-p" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
                        <a href="<?php echo $socialResult['gplus']; ?>" target = "_blank"> <i class="fa fa-google-plus" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
                        <a href="<?php echo $socialResult['ln']; ?>" target = "_blank"> <i class="fa fa-linkedin" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
                        <?php
                        }
                        }
                        ?>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </section>
        <!-- Navbar Starts -->
        <div class="row">
        <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
            <div class="container">
                <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
                <div class="navbar-header">
                    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
                        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    </button>
                    <a class="navbar-brand" href="../Template/index.php">
                    <?php
                    $slgQuery = "SELECT * FROM `title_slogan` WHERE `id`= '1'";
                    $getTitle = $db->select($slgQuery);
                    if($getTitle)
                    {
                        while($slgResult = $getTitle->fetch_assoc())
                        {
                    ?>
                  <img src="../Dashboard/admin/<?php echo $slgResult['logo'];?>" alt="logo" class="img-responsive">
                            <?php
                        }
                    }
                    ?>
                    </a>
                </div>
                <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right nav_link">
                        <?php
                        $path = $_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME'];
                        $currentPage = basename($path,'.php');
                        ?>
                        <li <?php if($currentPage == 'index'){echo 'class ="active"';}?>><a  href="../Template/index.php">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>

                        <li <?php if($currentPage == 'Excellent'){echo 'class ="active"';}?>>

                            <a  href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Post<span class="caret"></span></a>
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu nav_link"  aria-labelledby="dLabel">
                                <?php
                                if ($post){
                                while($result = $post->fetch_assoc())
                                {
                                ?>
                                <li><a href="../Template/Excellent.php?id=<?php echo $result['id'];?>"><p><?php echo $result['title'];?></p></a></li>
                                <?php }
                                }else{
                                    echo "data not Found!!";
                                }?>
                            </ul>

                        </li>
                          <?php
                         $aboutQuery = "select * from `tbl_page`";
                         $navigation = $db->select($aboutQuery);
                         if ($navigation)
                         {
                             while($aboutResult = $navigation->fetch_assoc())
                             {
                                 ?>

                        <li
                            <?php if (isset($_GET['pageid'])&& $_GET['pageid']== $aboutResult['id'])
                            {
                                echo 'class ="active"';
                            }
                            ?>
                        > <a href="../Template/page.php?pageid=<?php  echo $aboutResult['id'];?>"><?php  echo $aboutResult['name'];?>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                                 <?php
                             }
                         }
                        ?>
                        <li <?php if($currentPage == 'contact'){echo 'class ="active"';}?> ><a href="../Template/contact.php">Contact</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
            </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
        </nav>
        </div>
        <!-- Navbar Ends -->
    </header>
    <!-- header ended -->
```

**js.php**

```
   $('.nav_link li a').click(function (e) {
     e.preventDefault();
     var navPage= $(this).attr('href');
      //alert(navPage);
     $(document.body).load(navPage).fadeIn('slow');
     $(".dropdown-toggle").dropdown();
     if(navPage!==location.href){
         window.history.pushState({path:navPage},'',navPage);
     }
     return false;
 });
```

Comment: What did you want to do after ajax call?

Comment: I have 4 options is menu 1. Home, 2. post(dropdown).3. about(dynamic).4.Contact. When I click on home.The index.php load without refreshing. But i click on post, the dropdown menu won't work and it stuck,nothing happen but showed hash on url. I like to achieve, when click on every menu item another page load with change the url without refreshing the whole page.

Comment: Okay that's make sense, But URL of browser you mean?
See you can change the part's on the webpage but why URL ?

Comment: And very first add the <li id="nav_link"> Id on the UL i.e: <ul id="nav_link"> and remove from <li>

Comment: okay I understand what you asking.Actually i mean by url change like that..when i click on contact the url must be change like localhost/project/Template/contact.php from localhost/project/template/index.php. Does it make sense?

Comment: And the other thing is which ul i have to put the Id-nav-link. In the dropdown ul or at first.

Comment: First one <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">

Comment: Change it and still dropdown won't come out when click on post but other tpages worked fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Very First remove the `id="nav_link"` from `<li>` and add then add class on `<ul>`

I will recommend that you one class and to add on your both `<ul>`

From: `<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">`

To:   `<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right nav_link">`

Also for the secound `<ul>`
Add same class

Now change in the jquery

from: `$('#nav_link li a').click(function (e) {`

To: `$('.nav_link li a').click(function (e) {`

As # is for Id and . is for Class Learn more about this at here: [Selector](https://www.w3schools.com/Jquery/jquery_selectors.asp)

**Extra Update**

There are a lot of ways to do this but will let you know the one which is useful with current code
you need to stop the jquery code if there is `#` in the URL and that is for post menu

```
$('.nav_link li a').click(function (e) {
e.preventDefault();
var navPage= $(this).attr('href');
if(navPage != "#"){
    // your code
}
return false;
```

});

Comment: All my js script in js.php and my navigation menu on header.php.If i include js.php in header.php, php dynamically loadjs.php in all other pages.Because header.php included in all pages.so, now it is not working.But if i include js.php in every page,it worked but dropdown still remain the same..getting bored of this problem.

Comment: Load all the js and css on first page becuase you are not going to change the Page so you need to include everything on the default/first page.

Comment: Okay, what is the issue with dropdown?

Comment: thanks for asking.. okay, when i click on the menu option post, toggle a drop down menu with post title.then i can choose any one and click on that,it load post page.But now the dorpdown not working and the url remain localhost/project/Template/index.php/# like that

Comment: Check the page source you don't have url in the <a> tag or dropdown whatever,

Comment: check the li menu with page source It is not working because there is no URL at all.

Comment: okay the url is alright but dropdown is not working ,it suppose to work normally when click on post(menu option)

Comment: what i am trying to elaborate is menu option (post) going no where but when clicked just toggle a dropdown menu and then choose post to view

Comment: Yes, I understand, But just paste what you have added till now? so update the latest code in question.

Comment: When you click on post you don;t want to run the ajax you want to open the dropdown and form the dropdown you want to select submenu and on that menu you want to load the content M I right?